# How do I save my place in a text adventure (a function) to a file?

Tags: python, function, save

I'm starting a rudimentary text adventure game. I got a prototype working, but because each choice is a function, I can't figure out how to safely save my place in a file.

I considered saving the function's name to a file, but I can't think of a good way to get the function from its name as a `str` after reading the file. `eval` on an arbitrary `str` is notoriously unsafe. I considered a `dict` mapping every function to its name as a `str`, but it seems that as more choices pile up, this `dict` is gonna bloat my script.

```
def choice1():
    while True:
        text = input("A or B?: ")
        if text == "A":
            return False, choice2
        elif text == "B":
            saygameover()
            return True, None
        elif askedforsave(text):
            return True, choice1
        else:
            saytryagain()

def choice2():
    while True:
        text = input("C or D?: ")
        if text == "C":
            print("you win!")
            return True, None
        elif text == "D":
            saygameover()
            return True, None
        elif askedforsave(text):
            return True, choice2
        else:
            saytryagain()

def askedforsave(text):
    if text == "save":
        return True
    else:
        return False

def saytryagain():
    print("try again...")

def saygameover():
    print("game over.")

def play(choice = choice1):
    done = False
    while not done:
        done, choice = choice()
    if choice != None:
        save(choice)

def save(choice):
    pass

def load(file):
    pass
    return choice
```

Comment: You can store the choices in a `list` rather than a `dictionary`. And write the list into the file.

Comment: You know how to read and write to a file right?

Comment: Yes, I know how to read and write to a text file.

Comment: Can you also tell me how you are running the code. Whether you are calling the `choice1...` or is it another function?

Comment: You play the game by running `play()`. By default it starts at `choice1` but you can also start the game at other `choice`s.

Comment: Ok thanks for clarifying, I will try to find a solution.

Comment: Devise a Python class that maintains state then serialise the class (pickle)

Comment: @DarkKnight The `pickle` docs warns unpickling can execute arbitrary code, which is the same problem with `eval`. I suppose `eval` or unpickling would be fine if there is some way to check that the file only contains a valid Python variable name and then check that name exists in the module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I got so far. `isidentifier` is probably unnecessary when I'm already checking for a name in `globals()` but it's a good trick for making sure you're working with a valid Python name instead of an expression.

```
import types

def load(string):
        # if string is valid Python name
    if (string.isidentifier() and

        # if string in this global scope's symbol table
        string in (thisglobal := globals()) and

        # if object is a non-builtin function
        isinstance(something := thisglobal[string], types.FunctionType)):

        return something
    else:
        return nogame
    
def nogame():
    return True, None
```